# Can GNU gij be seen as a Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: jvm, java

I do not see gij listed as one of the Java Virtual Machines on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines and I have not found posts here talking about this either. Can anyone tell me whether gij is a JVM and if not, explain what's the missing in gij or what's the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [The Java Virtual Machine Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Introduction.doc.html#3032):

> However, the Java virtual machine does
>   not assume any particular
>   implementation technology, host
>   hardware, or host operating system. It
>   is not inherently interpreted, but can
>   just as well be implemented by
>   **compiling** its instruction set to that
>   of a silicon CPU. It may also be
>   implemented in microcode or directly
>   in silicon.

So GCJ can rightfully be called a Java Virtual Machine and GIJ, since it is an interpreter, even more so. The only requirement of a JVM is that it executes Java byte code.

If you look more closely at the Wikipedia page, you see GCJ in the bottom box listed in "Foundation and major implementations" of Java Virtual Machines.

Comment: Perhaps make note of other "Java-bytecode-processing" implementations (or partial implementations, perhaps a better term for GCJ ;-) such as [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) and how they may (or may not be) consider "JVMs" -- Dalvik, at least in the eyes of Wikipedia, is not a JVM. (One can argue compiling to Dalvik bytecode is no different than comping to machine instructions... which would make it a JVM per above... anyway). I think that, at the end of the day, this *has to be addressed in terms of compliance* (incl. all the nuances of the Java Memory Model, etc.)

Comment: In my eyes this is a matter of the "quality" of a JVM implementation. One implementation may be able to run bytecode programs correctly which others don't. And probably even the Oracle HotSpot VM does not execute some bytecode sequences as specified due to bugs. Also note that GCJ by itself is not a VM, only in combination with a processor which executes the compiled program. And still, it is not able to dynamically load class files as needed. This is where GIJ comes into play.

Comment: A relevant question: can GIJ be seen as a JRE as well? From wiki, there is no clear distinction between JRE. To emphasize that a JVM does not have the basic class libraries and the launcher, people sometimes call a ''naked'' (in my word) JVM as a standalone JVM. Are these terms you guys usually use?

Comment: @SDE A JVM executes Java bytecode. It is not responsible for providing a predefined set of libraries -- in the sense that a processor is not responsible for providing a C standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious reason not to call GNU gij a Java virtual machine ... modulo the obvious point that it could not ever be validated due to Oracle's stance on the TCK.

I'd say this is a "bug" in the Wikipedia list rather than a reflection on gij.

(Just looking through the list, I found and fixed another bug.  It said that JNode used GNU Classpath, which it hasn't done for a few years now.  If the list can get that wrong, it can be wrong about other things too.)

Comment: What?!  Wackypedia is **WRONG** on something?  But that's unpossible!!